# Query with multiple references to same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.  One with Contact information and the other with City ID and name.  Example.

```
Table 1 Contacts
ID,Name, HomeCity, BusinessCity
123,Ben,1,2

Table 2 Cities
CityID, CityName
1 Austin
2 Boston
```

I want to create a simple query that shows Ben's home city and business city.

**I don't understand how to include a query that references CityName twice.**

So far all I have is:

```
SELECT Contacts.Name, Contacts.HomeCity, Contacts.BusinessCity, Cities.CityName
FROM Contacts,Cities
WHERE Contacts.ID=123 AND Contacts.HomeCity=Cities.CityID
```

I just don't get it.  What I want the query to show me is:

```
Name, Home City, Business City
Ben, Austin, Boston
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax might not be perfect, but this general concept should work:

```
SELECT 
    Contacts.Name, 
    (SELECT CityName FROM Cities WHERE Contacts.HomeCity=Cities.CityID) AS HomeCity, 
    (SELECT CityName FROM Cities WHERE Contacts.BusinessCity=Cities.CityID) AS BusinessCity
FROM Contacts WHERE Contacts.ID=123
```

Answer (score 2):

You can join the contacts table to the cities table multiple times:

```
SELECT contacts.name, 
    cities.CityName 'Home City', 
    cities2.CityName 'Business City'
FROM contacts
    JOIN cities ON contacts.homecity = cities.cityid
    JOIN cities cities2 ON contacts.businesscity = cities2.cityid
WHERE contacts.ID=123
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3744f/1)

Depending on your desired results, you may need to use `OUTER JOINs` -- see the below link for additional information.

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)